# mod_rewrite .htaccess HTTPS

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to force the browser to redirect to HTTPS always if someone types in:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/user
or
http://www.mydomain.com/user/
```

Both of the above 2 links should redirect to: `https://www.mydomain.com/user`

Right now the 2nd to bottom line of code works correctly:

```
RewriteRule ^user$ https://www.mydomain.com/user/ [R,QSA]
```

will indeed redirect the browser to HTTPS but if `http://www.mydomain.com/user/` is input then it won't redirect to HTTPS. How can I achieve this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^user$ https://www.mydomain.com/user/ [R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/$ public/index.php?var1=x&var2=y [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force www domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# force HTTPS for some pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/?$ https://www.mydomain.com/user/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/$ public/index.php?var1=x&var2=y [L,QSA]
```

It will redirect to HTTPS:

- if HTTP is current protocol (so no redirection if already on HTTPS)
- regardless of trailing slash presence: both `/user` and `/user/` will do the job (but will do nothing if `/user/something-here` will be requested).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne this is exactly what I was looking for and I understand now why because the "?" mark makes it an ungreedy modifier.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ...

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/?$  public/index.php?var1=x&var2=y [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^user/?$       https://www.mydomain.com/user/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$       http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So that ends up in an infinite loop and the browser stops :(.  You essentially get:

http://www.mydomain.com/https:/www.mydomain.com/login/ as the message in Safari when I just tested.

Comment: Yeah this is giving me an Internal Server Error.